# Get inheriting class name in base class' class method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have Models in my Flask app. I create tables from those models, and insert data into those tables. However, when I insert into those tables I want to log what I am inserting and which table I am inserting into. I have a "create" class method in my BaseModel which all other Models inherit from. I want to log the class name of the inherited Model in this "create" method. When I do so using

```
cls.__class__.__name__
```

it gives me the value "DefaultMeta". I want it to give me the Model name, for example, User.

Here is my create method in my BaseModel:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
        )
    create_date = db.Column(
        db.DateTime,
        default=datetime.utcnow()
        )
    update_date = db.Column(
        db.DateTime,
        default=datetime.utcnow(),
        onupdate=db.func.now()
        )

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        current_app.logger.info('Creating {} with args: {}'.format(cls.__class__.__name__, kwargs))
        obj = cls(**kwargs)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
        return obj
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cls.__class__.__name__` is the class's class's name. You want the class's name. That's `cls.__name__`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Bit of a stupid mistake but I wouldn't have caught that for a while!